# Locational & headshot damage in Battlefield 1

Tags: battlefield-1

Sometimes I feel like I'm taking far too much damage from certain weapons while not doing enough with my own. Now that's mainly because I'm terrible at shooters but I'd still like to know how the damage is calculated and where I should aim at in order to maximize my damage output (apart from the head).

My questions regarding the locational damage are:

- Is there locational damage apart from headshots/non-headshots
- What are the multipliers for the different hit zones
- Do the multipliers vary based on weapon/distance etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Body part damage multipliers**

*General Multipliers

For all bullets except ones in special multipliers category*

- Headshot    1.7x
- Upper body  1.0x
- Lower body and upper arms   0.96x
- Legs and forearms   0.96x

**Special multipliers**

*Scout's primary weapons (100 max damage, no M1903 Experimental)*

- Headshot    1.8x
- Upper body  1.0x
- Lower body and upper arms   0.9x
- Legs and forearms   0.75x

*Shotgun slugs, Gewehr M.95, Russian 1895 Trench*

- Headshot    1.8x
- Upper body  1.0x
- Lower body and upper arms   0.93x
- Legs and forearms   0.93x

*Shotgun buckshots*

- Headshot    1.1x
- Upper body  1.0x
- Lower body and upper arms   1.0x
- Legs and forearms   0.9x

Not sure on multipliers, but damage does change depending on weapon, distance, and location.

Stats from [Symthic site](http://symthic.com/bf1-general-info?p=damage-multipliers)

Comment: And what does this site have that is applicable to this question?  I'm afraid we don't allow answers that just link elsewhere to find out the information; it's another step for readers to click through, and what happens if the site goes down?  The answer is no longer helpful at all.  Summarizing the information from the linked site will ensure your answer is still valid even if the site goes down or is no longer available.

Comment: I apologize. The site contains statics on weapons, hitboxes, damage multipliers and much more for the Battle Field 1 game. There is a lot of information. I will update my answer.

Comment: Excellent.  Much better.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: I'd point out that in BF games (but not some other FPS games), damage falls off greatly with distance.  This is something that is asked about in the question, but not addressed in this answer.  There is a damage vs distance chart for guns that is shown in-game, and I think it might be a good idea to add a reference and screenshot of that chart to address that part of the original question.  The locational data from Symthic is all good stuff too, of course.